# MySQL join rather than subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

Hey guys I want to something like this:

```
DELETE FROM ClientsFlags 
WHERE clientId = (SELECT id 
                  FROM Client 
                  WHERE emailRegistrationToken = 3) 
AND flagId = 42;
```

But with a join rather than the sub query. I'm not very good with joins so please help me out.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a join version,

```
DELETE  a
FROM    ClientsFlags a
        INNER JOIN Client b
            ON a.clientId = b.id
WHERE   b.emailRegistrationToken = 3 AND            
        a.flagId = 42;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`Delete C From ClientFlags cf, Client c where cf.lientId=c.Id and email=3 and flagId=42;`

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this :

```
 DELETE C FROM ClientsFlags AS CF
 JOIN Client AS C ON C.Id=CF.clientId 
 WHERE email=3 and flagId=42
```